# UWP WebView doesn't render correctly when not in visual tree

Tags: c#, webview, win-universal-app

I'm using the concept of loading a WebView and its content in the background (aka WebView is not in the Visual Tree) so the WebView and its HTML content is ready / loaded and stored in memory.
At some point later I add the WebView to the visual tree to show its content. Because it's already loaded and stored in memory, it should not show any sign of loading - it just pops up ready to use.

This works fine on desktop UWP apps. However, Windows Mobile has an issue. When I add the WebView to the Visual Tree, its HTML content displays very small (unreadable) or huge, depending on the screen size. The weirdest part is: when I touch the screen, it suddenly zooms in to its normal size (as it should be).

Now, I've already tested a scenario where I add the WebView to the Visual Tree, load it, wait 50 ms, remove it from the Visual Tree and store it in memory. When I display it later, it renders correctly (normal size).

The project I'm working on is a SDK / library and I don't want to require the users of the SDK to register a view so I can implement the workaround above. 
Is there any way of loading a WebView in the background, adding it to the Visual Tree later and the HTML content shows properly?

The SDK / library is built for UWP (Universal Windows Platform) apps, targeting both desktop and mobile.

EDIT:
I've found another workaround, without registering a view as described above.

1. Load the WebView (not in visual tree), navigate to the local HTML file
2. Store it in memory
3. Some time later: load it from memory
4. Add it to the visual tree
5. Set the width of the WebView to 1
6. Add a Task.Delay(1)
7. Set the width of the WebView to double.NaN

Voila. Renders as expected. It just looks like the WebView doesn't detect it's been added to the visual tree and doesn't re-render its HTML.